# Discrepancy in php DateTime() on Windows and Linux

Tags: php, windows-10, linux-mint

I have a php application that calls the following:

```
$today = new DateTime();
echo "Today's date: ".$today->format('m-d-Y');
```

Given that "today" = 08-31-2015, on a Linux Mint 17 server it shows 08-31-2015.  On a Windows 10 server, 09-01-2015.

This is a dual boot machine and I've checked the clock on each OS and they are in sync time/date-wise, and both set to Central time zone.

The attached image is the Windows clock setting, just to prove my sanity.  Thoughts, anyone?

[image: Windows 10 date/time settings]

Comment: Is the timezone in php.ini set to the same on each server as well?

Comment: Along with @skrilled, to test `date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');`

Comment: Aha!  Thanks to both.  Didn't think of that.